# Update the dataframe based on a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like below and have millions of records, so I want to add column for total_score and expected_score. If `region1` has "all region" then add columns `t_region1`, `t_region2`, `t_region3` and add values from `total_score`.

Same needed to do for `expected_score`.

```
df <- data.frame(total_score=c(4.5,12.2,4.6,9.2,12.2,36.4),
                 expected_score=c(4.5,12.1,NA,9.2,12.2,NA),
                 Region1=c("All region",NA,NA,"All region","All region",NA),
                 Region2=c("EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST",NA),
                 Region3=c("West",NA,"West","West","West","West"))
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the logic here, since there is only one value for each `Region*` column

Comment: so actually t_region1, tregion_2,_t_region3 taking values from total_score, and same as  e_region1, e_region_2,e_region3 will be taking values from expected_score column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)


col_names <- paste0("t_region", 1:3)

## the names can be changed as desired, see the commented out code below for examples
# col_names <- paste0("t_", c("east", "west", "north", "south"))
# col_names <- c("total_east", "west_total", "north", "SOUTH")

tibble(!!!col_names) %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(col_names), 
                  ~ifelse(Region1 == "All region", total_score, NA)))
```

```
#>   total_score expected_score    Region1 Region2 Region3 t_region1 t_region2 t_region3 
#> 1         4.5            4.5 All region    EAST    West       4.5       4.5       4.5
#> 2        12.2           12.1       <NA>    EAST    <NA>        NA        NA        NA
#> 3         4.6             NA       <NA>    EAST    West        NA        NA        NA
#> 4         9.2            9.2 All region    EAST    West       9.2       9.2       9.2
#> 5        12.2           12.2 All region    EAST    West      12.2      12.2      12.2
#> 6        36.4             NA       <NA>    <NA>    West        NA        NA        NA
```

---

### Update 2:

Based on what the OP mentioned in the comments, I guess they are looking to get the expected and total scores for each region if they are present in the Region## columns. That is a little bit different from what they described in the question, but makes more sense based on their comments.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  unite("region", Region1:Region3, sep = "___", na.rm = T, remove = FALSE) %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(region, "___") %>% 
  mutate(t_= total_score, e_ = expected_score) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = region, values_from = c(t_, e_), names_sep = "") %>% 
  rename_with(~gsub("\\s+", "_", .x), contains(" "))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  total_score expected_score Region1    Region2 Region3 t_All_region t_EAST t_West e_All_region e_EAST e_West
        <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1         4.5            4.5 All region EAST    West             4.5    4.5    4.5          4.5    4.5    4.5
2        12.2           12.1 NA         EAST    NA              NA     12.2   NA           NA     12.1   NA  
3         4.6           NA   NA         EAST    West            NA      4.6    4.6         NA     NA     NA  
4         9.2            9.2 All region EAST    West             9.2    9.2    9.2          9.2    9.2    9.2
5        12.2           12.2 All region EAST    West            12.2   12.2   12.2         12.2   12.2   12.2
6        36.4           NA   NA         NA      West            NA     NA     36.4         NA     NA     NA
```

---

##### Original Answer:

Here I am creating a list column with values from `total_score` if `Region1 == "All region"`. Then I `unnest_...` the new column to get our expected output. Exact same thing can be done for `expected_score` to get `e_region` columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(t_region = if_else(Region1 == "All region", 
                            list(rep(total_score, 3)), 
                            list(rep(NA, 3)))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(t_region, names_sep = "")
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  total_score expected_score Region1    Region2 Region3 t_region1 t_region2 t_region3
        <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1         4.5            4.5 All region EAST    West          4.5       4.5       4.5
2        12.2           12.1 NA         EAST    NA           NA        NA        NA  
3         4.6           NA   NA         EAST    West         NA        NA        NA  
4         9.2            9.2 All region EAST    West          9.2       9.2       9.2
5        12.2           12.2 All region EAST    West         12.2      12.2      12.2
6        36.4           NA   NA         NA      West         NA        NA        NA
```

Comment: `rowwise` is very slow

Comment: if i want to make it t_region1 t_region2 t_region3 , like , t_all_employee, t_east,t_west then ...??

Comment: so actually in place of names like t_region1, t_region2, i want to give names of t_all region, t_east, t_west etc then ...??

Comment: its still the same, names should be t_all region, t_east, t_west etc in place of   t_region1, t_region2. may be i was not  able to explain

Comment: @samrr_tr Just replace `col_names <- paste0("t_region", 1:3)` with `col_names <- paste0("t_", c("east", "west", "north", "south", "etc."))` or whatever other column names that you need. The output matches your desired output though. If you have a condition for the names (based on Region2 or something) then you need post another question with the desired output. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can quickly create the columns and fill them with the relevant values using [indexing]:

```
newcols <- paste0("t_region", 1:3)

df[df$Region1 %in% "All region", newcols] <- df[df$Region1 %in% "All region", "total_score"]
```

Output:

```
  total_score expected_score    Region1 Region2 Region3 t_region1 t_region2 t_region3
1         4.5            4.5 All region    EAST    West       4.5       4.5       4.5
2        12.2           12.1       <NA>    EAST    <NA>        NA        NA        NA
3         4.6             NA       <NA>    EAST    West        NA        NA        NA
4         9.2            9.2 All region    EAST    West       9.2       9.2       9.2
5        12.2           12.2 All region    EAST    West      12.2      12.2      12.2
6        36.4             NA       <NA>    <NA>    West        NA        NA        NA
```